# Connect a vertex to a pre-existing edge

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges

I have a vertex that needs to connect to an edge. I'd rather not have to subdivide the edge and just connect it... It seems too manual... Is it possible?
[image]

Comment: Use a knife cut. K shorcut.

Answer (score 0):

Its certainly not possible and not preferable because at whatever place you join two edges you add a vertex , so you cant just join them , you need to have 2 vertices to join